# Shell globbing exclude directory patterns

Tags: bash, shell, glob

Disregarding commands that can be used in association with shell globs, I would like to accomplish excluding specific directory patterns across all directories and sub-directories from a glob pattern.

Let's say I have this directory structure:

```
+-- a
    +-- a1
         +-- assets
                  +-- a1-1
                         +-- a1-1.js
                  +-- a1-2
                         +-- a1-2.js
    +-- a2
         +-- a2.js
+-- b
    +-- b1
         +-- b1-2
                +-- b1-2-3
                         +-- assets
                                  +-- b1-2-3.js
    +-- b.js
+-- c
    +-- c.js
```

I would like to list all js files that do not have `assets` in their file paths.

What I've tried so far:

```
$ shopt -s globstar extglob
$ ls ./**/!(assets)/**/*.js
```

Not only did the pattern above achieve its goal, it even shows duplicate outputs. I am aware that I can do something like this:

```
$ ls ./**/*.js | grep -v "assets"
```

Or any other commands that can be piped, I simply want a pure shell glob pattern.

Expected Output:

```
a/a2/a2.js  
b/b.js  
c/c.js
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Michael's answer is right. `**` matches too much (greedy match), including `assets`.

So, with this tree:

```
.
|-- a
|   |-- a1
|   |   +-- assets
|   |       |-- a1-1
|   |       |   +-- a1-1.js
|   |       +-- a1-2
|   |           +-- a1-2.js
|   +-- a2
|       +-- a2.js
|-- assets
|   +-- xyz.js
|-- b
|   |-- b1
|   |   +-- b1-2
|   |       +-- b1-2-3
|   |           |-- assets
|   |           |   +-- b1-2-3.js
|   |           +-- test
|   |               |-- test2
|   |               |   +-- test3
|   |               |       +-- test4
|   |               |           +-- test4.js
|   |               +-- test.js
|   +-- b.js
|-- c
|   +-- c.js
+-- x.js
```

The .js files are:

```
$ find . -name '*.js'
./x.js
./assets/xyz.js
./a/a2/a2.js
./a/a1/assets/a1-2/a1-2.js
./a/a1/assets/a1-1/a1-1.js
./c/c.js
./b/b.js
./b/b1/b1-2/b1-2-3/test/test2/test3/test4/test4.js
./b/b1/b1-2/b1-2-3/test/test.js
./b/b1/b1-2/b1-2-3/assets/b1-2-3.js
```

There is a bash variable [`GLOBIGNORE`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#GLOBIGNORE) to do exactly what you are trying to do.

So, this would work:

```
$ GLOBIGNORE='**/assets/**:assets/**:**/assets'
$ ls -1 **/*.js
a/a2/a2.js
b/b1/b1-2/b1-2-3/test/test2/test3/test4/test4.js
b/b1/b1-2/b1-2-3/test/test.js
b/b.js
c/c.js
x.js
```

Comment: Sorry, but this solution only shows js files from the one to two levels of directories, any js files beyond that is not listed.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `**` matches too much or too little in your case. In particular, the `**` preceding `!(assets)` will match `a1/assets/`, then `!(assets)` will match `a1-1` and the following `**` will match nothing, so that the overall match succeeds.

Consider this simplified example:

```
touch a/a1/x.js a/a2/y.js a/a3/z.js
ls ./*/!(a2)/*.js
ls ./**/!(a2)/**/*.js
```

The first `ls` works as intended, the second does not.

Comment: This works, because the directory structure you have in your example is organized in the same level. The problem at hand is that the `assets` directory resides in deeper and different levels. This does not solve the problem at all.

Comment: @ryeballar No, it does not. But it explains why the attempt fails. That is not nothing.

Comment: True, I guess this could be a limitation in globbing. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This might be the perfect time for you to start using `zsh` :-) Removing matches is simply done with `~`:

```
% setopt extended_glob
% ls -1 **/*.js~*assets*
a/a2/a2.js
b/b.js
c/c.js
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is something you search for a lot, then I'd just write a simple script.

For testing, set up files and directories, as described in the question:

*(notice added c/assets.js to test edge case)*:

```
mkdir -p a/a1/assets/a1-1 a/a1/assets/a1-2 a/a2 b/b1/b1-2/b1-2-3/assets c
touch a/a1/assets/a1-1/a1-1.js a/a1/assets/a1-2/a1-2.js a/a2/a2.js b/b1/b1-2/b1-2-3/assets/b1-2-3.js b/b.js c/c.js
touch c/assets.js
```

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar  # enable ** to recurse all the directories

files=()  # create array variable

for f in **/*.js; do  # glob pattern match all .js files
  if [[ ! "$f" =~ "assets/" ]]; then  # regex match all paths that do NOT contain an 'assets' directory
    files+=("$f")  # add it to the files array
  fi
done

printf %s\\n "${files[@]}"  # print the files array
```

Results:

```
a/a2/a2.js
b/b.js
c/assets.js
c/c.js
```